# How do I change the font size of the password prompt for an encrypted disk in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, fonts

I have Debian Buster set up to use whole disk encryption so it prompts me when booting with a message "Please unlock disk..." and asks for my password.

The issue is that my laptop has a 4k screen, so the font is very tiny.

How do I change the font size of this password prompt (or the resolution at that point in the boot) so it is more readable?